# How an ANTLR visitor or listener can be written with async/await on its methods?

Tags: javascript, async-await, antlr4

I am creating a grammar to compile the parser as a JavaScript parser.

Then I would like to use async/await to call asynchronous functions within the visitor or listener.

As the default generated code does not include async in the functions, await is not allowed.

How could this be achieved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really define listeners using `async` because listener methods can't return anything (or rather their return values aren't used), so nothing would be done with the returned promises.

However, using `async` in *visitors* works perfectly fine. Just define your `visitFoo` methods as `async` and use `await` as you please. For example:

```
class Interpreter extends MyLangVisitor {
    async visitSleep(sleepCtx) {
        let p = new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(resolve, sleepCtx.amount.text)
        });
        await p;
    }

    async visitProgram(programCtx) {
        for(let command of programCtx.commands) {
            await this.visit(command);
        }
    }
}
```

This will work fine because `this.visit(command)` simply returns the result of `this.visitSleep(command)` (or whichever other method applies), which will be a promise. So you're awaiting the promise returned by `visitSleep` and everything works out fine.

Do note that you shouldn't use the default `visitChildren` method when your methods are `async` because that will visit all the children without `await`ing them. You can easily define your own version  though:

```
async visitChildren(ctx) {
    for(let child of ctx.children) {
        await this.visit(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even that the listener methods do not return value, they could executed with await. I am going to investigate how to add this to the code generation of ANTLR4 https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/resources/org/antlr/v4/tool/templates/codegen/JavaScript/JavaScript.stg